# MAUI: UI alignment issue in Listview with Grid having 3 columns

Tags: listview, grid, maui

I have a UI alignment issue in Listview with Grid having 3 columns like the below screenshot:

[image]

**My ListView Code:**

```
<ListView 
    x:Name="MyCustomers"
    ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems,Mode=TwoWay}"
    RowHeight="{OnIdiom Phone=80, Tablet=110, Desktop=80}"
    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
    HasUnevenRows="True"
    CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"     
    RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
    IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <Grid 
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Grid Grid.Column="0"
                              HorizontalOptions="Start">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="12.25*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Grid 
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                Grid.Column="1">
                                <Image 
                                    Source="ic_profilebg_xx.png"
                                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                    x:Name="imagebg"
                                    Aspect="AspectFit">
                                    <Image.HeightRequest>
                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                            <OnIdiom.Phone>60</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>90</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>60</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                        </OnIdiom>
                                    </Image.HeightRequest>
                                    <Image.WidthRequest>
                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                            <OnIdiom.Phone>60</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>90</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>60</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                        </OnIdiom>
                                    </Image.WidthRequest>
                                </Image>
                                <Label 
                                    Text="{Binding user.fullname,Converter={StaticResource profilenameConverter}}"
                                    Style="{StaticResource InitalLabelStyle}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>

                        <StackLayout
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="3,0,0,0"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            Orientation="Vertical">

                            <Label 
                                Text="{Binding user.fullname, Converter={StaticResource nameConverter}}"
                                FontFamily="Bold" 
                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                TextColor="#676767"
                                IsVisible="{Binding user.fullname,  Converter={StaticResource nullCheckConverter}}">
                                <Label.FontSize>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                        <OnIdiom.Phone>15</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>20</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>15</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                    </OnIdiom>
                                </Label.FontSize>
                            </Label>

                            <Label 
                                Text="{Binding user.email}"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                TextColor="#676767"
                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                 HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                IsVisible="{Binding user.email ,  Converter={StaticResource nullCheckConverter}}">
                                <Label.FontSize>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                        <OnIdiom.Phone>12</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>18</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>12</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                    </OnIdiom>
                                </Label.FontSize>
                            </Label>

                            <Label 
                                Text="{Binding phoneNumber, Converter={StaticResource phoneNumberFormatConverter}}"
                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                 HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                TextColor="#676767"
                                IsVisible="{Binding isPhoneEmpty}">
                                <Label.FontSize>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                        <OnIdiom.Phone>12</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>18</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>12</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                    </OnIdiom>
                                </Label.FontSize>
                            </Label>
                            <!--<StackLayout.WidthRequest>
                                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                    <OnIdiom.Phone>200</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                    <OnIdiom.Tablet>300</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                    <OnIdiom.Desktop>200</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                </OnIdiom>
                            </StackLayout.WidthRequest>-->
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout 
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            Orientation="Vertical"
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">

                            <StackLayout 
                                Margin="0,0,0,5"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                BackgroundColor="#5abcd7">

                                <Label 
                                    Text="{Binding pointsToVisualize}"
                                    FontFamily="Bold" 
                                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    TextColor="White">
                                    <Label.FontSize>
                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                            <OnIdiom.Phone>15</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>20</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>15</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                        </OnIdiom>
                                    </Label.FontSize>
                                </Label>
                                <!--<StackLayout.WidthRequest>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                        <OnIdiom.Phone>80</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>120</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>80</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                    </OnIdiom>
                                </StackLayout.WidthRequest>-->
                                <StackLayout.Padding>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                                        <OnIdiom.Phone>3</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>6</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>3</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                    </OnIdiom>
                                </StackLayout.Padding>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout
                                Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <Image
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    Source="ic_action_time.png">
                                    <Image.WidthRequest>
                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                            <OnIdiom.Phone>13</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>20</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>13</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                        </OnIdiom>
                                    </Image.WidthRequest>
                                    <Image.HeightRequest>
                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                            <OnIdiom.Phone>13</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>20</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>13</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                        </OnIdiom>
                                    </Image.HeightRequest>
                                </Image>

                                <Label 
                                    Margin="2,0,0,0"
                                    Text="{Binding user.updatedTime,  Converter={StaticResource cnvDateTimeConverter}}"
                                    TextColor="#5abcd7"
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                    VerticalOptions="Center">
                                    <Label.FontSize>
                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                            <OnIdiom.Phone>10</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>15</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>10</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                        </OnIdiom>
                                    </Label.FontSize>
                                </Label>
                                <StackLayout.Margin>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                                        <OnIdiom.Phone>3</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>6</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>3</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                    </OnIdiom>
                                </StackLayout.Margin>
                                <!--<StackLayout.WidthRequest>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                        <OnIdiom.Phone>115</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>300</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>50</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                    </OnIdiom>
                                </StackLayout.WidthRequest>-->
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <Grid.Margin>
                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                                <OnIdiom.Phone>3</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                <OnIdiom.Tablet>6</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                <OnIdiom.Desktop>3</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                            </OnIdiom>
                        </Grid.Margin>
                        <Grid.Padding>
                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                                <OnIdiom.Phone>3</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                <OnIdiom.Tablet>6</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                <OnIdiom.Desktop>3</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                            </OnIdiom>
                        </Grid.Padding>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.Footer>
        <Label/>
    </ListView.Footer>
</ListView>
```

I tried to recreate this issue on a demo project and in the demo it is working fine. The demo project is uploaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hpaY2paaAg_YDuepFQnmnNLwd_zLZoIX/view?usp=sharing).

With the same codes the UI has no issue in demo project and has issues in my real project, what may be the possible reason?

Note: If I uncomment the `StackLayout.WidthRequest` for the second column the UI alignment issue is getting resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have copied your project and reproduced your problem.

> With the same codes the UI has no issue in demo project and has issues in my real project, what may be the possible reason?

This is becase all the items of the listview in the demo project is the same. But your real project has different data for each item **(the stacklayouts have different width)**.

> If I uncomment the StackLayout.WidthRequest for the second column the UI alignment issue is getting resolved.

This is because you make each item's width same. And I found the  `HorizontalOptions="Start"` in the StackLayout didn't work for your project (target .net 7.0). But I tested the same code in the .net 8.0 and the `HorizontalOptions="Start"` worked well. The UI alignment issue disappeared.

**So you can try to upgrade your project to target net 8.0 to fix this issue.** And you can [report this on the repo](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).

Comment: Hope you are mentioning about the `HorizontalOptions="Start"` for the second column having name, email and phone number

Comment: Yes, I mean the second column. It doesn't work for .net 7.0. You can add a background color for the stacklayout and you will find it didn't at the start. So I suggest you upgrade to .net 8.0. @MatthewPans

Comment: I updated to net 8.0 and added color, but there is a large space between the blue bubble and name part, check the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcuRG.jpg Any idea why this much of space?

Comment: Also the points layout is not in the same line, some of them are going inside and some are going outside, not in a straight line

Comment: For the first question, this is because the first column is not filled. You can add the `HorizontalOptions="Fill"` for the Grid in the first column. @MatthewPans

Comment: Can you point out the **the points layout is not in the same line**? @MatthewPans

Comment: I think the `points layout is not in the same line` issue is an illusion, check the below screenshot, the last column is starting from the same point for all items. Right? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt9X2.jpg

Comment: Yes, I see they are in the same line. @MatthewPans

Comment: After updating to .net 8 I am facing some issues, could you please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78153002/maui-the-app-is-working-fine-in-debug-mode-and-craches-with-the-apk-published-o